# AspectJ - Cannot register non aspect error

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to play with AspectJ and run time weaving.
I have created an aspect

```
  @Aspect(value = "TraceAspect")
public class TraceAspect {
   @Around("execution(* *(..))")
   public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint invocation) throws Throwable{

     System.out.println(String.format("Invocing %s", invocation.getSignature().getName()));
     try {
      Object ret = invocation.proceed();
      System.out.println(String.format("Done Invocing %s", invocation.getSignature().getName()));
      return ret;
     } catch (Throwable throwable) {
       throw throwable;

     }

   }
}
```

and my aop.xml file is

```
<aspectj>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="TraceAscpect"></aspect>
</aspects>
<weaver options="-debug -showWeaveInfo"/>
```

however when I run the program I get exception -

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot register non aspect: TraceAscpect , TraceAscpect
```

What did I forget to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have spelt the name of your aspect wrong in your XML definition, it should be `TraceAspect` and you've put `TraceAscpect`.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Andy correct the typo in XML file. I also got the same exception. Later I realised that my aspect was not on the CLASSPATH. This fixed the issue for me. Make it sure that `TraceAspect` is on your CLASSPATH.

Comment: that's called a comment